# Why is this 3d json file so shiny in three.js?

Tags: mesh, materials, three.js

I've tried everything to take that shine off. Turned 'shininess' down, specular, turned the lights way down low, everything. Why is it still so insanely shiny? :D

[Here's my code](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/5/) 
([and the json model file](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/5/models/errari-laferrari.json)). Takes a while to load.

Comment: You can demonstrate this with a much smaller file too, use a Suzanne or something and try to reproduce it.

Comment: Maybe the settings are completely different in Suzanne?

Comment: That's exactly my point, the subject of the model is not what's causing the high specularity. it's a materials vs lights vs polygon density thing. Investigate other models of cars shown in three.js to see if you can learn from them.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Polygon density? How does that alter the specularity?

Comment: imagine if you have a curved surface, and two meshes . one with super high density, the other with barely enough polygons to give a the surface its curvature. The mesh with the low density but high specularity will have fewer normals to average between, and will show its brightest spots as much larger areas. Higher density is more normals, and fewer faces that directly aim the light bounces into the camera.

Comment: you could show this problem even if you deleted a lot of things from the model (make a duplicate .blend and edit it down ) and removed all geometry (seats..glass..rims..tires..steering wheel,..) except a quarter of the the body -- that would reduce the size of the model a lot and make the question into something more generic and helpful to others -- it would focus on the problem area. nice model btw.

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured some of it out, it has a specocc texture file on it.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own Question, even if it's a short paragraph about what the problem was and how you solved it. This could help someone else in the future.